# How to know when "promener" takes an accent or not?

Tags: orthographe, conjugaison, diacritiques

The conjugation of the verb *promener* can be quite confusing:

1. We write *je me promène* in the first person singular present.
2. We write *nous nous promenons* in the first person plural present.
3. We write *je me suis promené(e)* in the first person singular compound past.

I am a French Native so I usually decide to put an accent on the first e depending on the pronunciation. *Je me promene* and *Nous nous proménons* would simply sound awkward.

**But how can a French learner  easily know when to put an accent when conjugating *Promener* or similar verbs (*appeler*, *jeter*)?**

Is there a simple rule, either linguistic/grammatical/logical or mnemotechnic? Or is memorizing, and a lot of practice, speaking and listening,  the only way to go?

Note: I am asking the question in order to help a friend who is learning French, so answers in English are preferred, but I can translate answers in French.

Comment: La seule règle simple c'est la terminaison **é** dans la formation du participe passé des verbes en -er (je te conseille l'appellation verbes en -er dans la mesure où tu t'adresses à un non francophone, et non pas verbes du er groupe). Sinon il n'y a aucune règle **simple** mais une série de règles qui dépendent de de la consonne qui suit et une série d'exceptions.

Comment: Pour te faire une idée : pour les verbes en [~eler et ~eter](https://www.ortholud.com/code/les-verbes.php?terminaison=eler,%20eter), un article sur la question ; [Un problème orthographique difficile à résoudre : les verbes en -eler, -eter](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1973_num_20_1_5650). La question est donc très vaste.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule you can say that the accent is needed when follows

- one phonetic syllable in which the nucleus is /ə/ (schwa, pronounced or not)

There can be one or two syllables after le syllable in which the e in question is the nucleus.

That corresponds to the moods, tenses and persons listed next;

Indicatif

- *Présent* je promèn**e**, tu promèn**e**s, il promèn**e**, ils promèn**e**nt
- *Passé simple* ils promenèr**e**nt
- *Futur* je promèn**e**rai, tu promèn**e**ras, il promèn**e**ra, nous promèn**e**rons, vous promèn**e**rez
  ils promèn**e**ront

*Conditionnel*

- *Présent*  je promèn**e**rais, tu promèn**e**rais, il promèn**e**rait, nous promèn**e**rions,vous promèn**e**riez, ils promèn**e**raient

*Subjonctif*

- *Présent* que je promèn**e**, que tu promèn**e**s, qu'il promèn**e**, qu'ils promèn**e**nt

---

The remaining forms rarely have in that syllable an e that is not schwa;

Indicatif

Présent 
nous promen**o**ns
vous promen**e**z

Imparfait 
je promen**ai**s
tu promenais
il promenait
nous promen**io**ns
vous promen**ie**z
ils promenaient

Passé simple je promen**ai**
tu promen**as**
il promen**a**
nous promen**â**mes
vous promen**â**tes

Conditionnel

Présent

Subjonctif

Présent 
que nous promen**io**ns
que vous promen**ie**z

Impératif

Présent
promen**o**ns
promen**e**z

Participe

Présent promen**a**nt

Passé promen**é**

---

As a graphical rule, you can say that the accent is needed every time the nucleus of the following syllable is represented by graphic e, except in the case of "promenez" because e before z is [e], not schwa.